# Get distinct datatypes within the same Series in Pandas

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, types, series

Let's say we have a pandas series which contains a mixture of datatypes as below (string, int and datetime)

If i check the dtype on the diff_series (`diff_series.dtype`), it shows me that it's an object as expected. I would like to get the distinct datatypes that are in the series. I have the following list comprehension which gets me the unique dtypes in a series.

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd

>> diff_series = pd.Series(['1','2',3,"random_text",datetime.datetime.now()])
>> set([type(i) for i in diff_series])

   set([<type 'str'>, <type 'datetime.datetime'>, <type 'int'>])
```

But i get a feeling that there should be a more efficient (pandonic) way of going about doing this ?

I tried

```
>> diff_series.get_dtype_counts()

   object    1
   dtype: int64
```

which is not what im looking for. Any ideas ?

Comment: FYI, i'm on Pandas 0.17.1

Comment: Although I think it is understood what you meant, it is important to note that the datatypes that are *in the series* is simply `object`.

Answer (score 5):

We could do something like:

```
In [4]: diff_series.map(type).value_counts()
Out[4]: 
<class 'str'>                  3
<class 'datetime.datetime'>    1
<class 'int'>                  1
dtype: int64
```

Or, might as well "go all out":

```
In [5]: diff_series.map(type).value_counts().index.values
Out[5]: array([<class 'str'>, <class 'datetime.datetime'>, <class 'int'>], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 3):

This should be more pandonic:

```
diff_series.apply(type)

0                  <type 'str'>
1                  <type 'str'>
2                  <type 'int'>
3                  <type 'str'>
4    <type 'datetime.datetime'>
dtype: object
```